# How to change the variable value without changing its * value?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am a newbie in the C language and learning it. I am learning the pointers. I am confused a little about the following program.

My question is it even possible to get the **outcome B** ever? I am changing the value of **a** but accordingly, the value of **b** gets changed due to the pointer and I am always just getting **outcome A**. How can I get **outcome B**? Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
 void increment(int value) {
    value++;
}
int main() {
   int a = 6;
   int *b = &a;
   increment(a); 
   if(a == *b) {
     printf("outcome A");
   } else if(a > *b) {
     printf("outcome B");
   } else {
     printf("outcome C");
   } return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `increment` function does not work as you intended. `a` will still equal `6` within `main` after you called `increment(a)` since you are passing a copy of `a` to it which gets incremented

Comment: If you want a function to modify a variable, you have to pass a pointer (e.g. `void increment(int *value) { (*value)++; }` and `int a = 6; increment(&a);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) is an object in many programming languages that stores a memory address. A pointer references a location in memory, and obtaining the value stored at that location is known as dereferencing the pointer

Take a look at this code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a = 6;
   int *b = &a;
   
   printf("a = %d  b = %p  *b = %d\n", a, (void*)b, *b); 
    
   a = 20;

   printf("a = %d  b = %p  *b = %d\n", a, (void*)b, *b); 
}
```

Output:

```
a = 6  b = 0x7fff3ead8d6c  *b = 6
a = 20  b = 0x7fff3ead8d6c  *b = 20
```

As you can see, assigning a new value to a did not change the value of b. It did change the value pointed to by b, however. That is, b did not change, while *b did.